# Does toCharArray() consumes space in Big O

Tags: java, arrays, string, big-o, space-complexity

In calculating the space complexity of algorithms, we're told the easiest way to find out about additional space is the creation of a data structure like Set, Map, Stack etc.

Take the below code as example that reveres a string (In Java)

```
private String reverse(String string){

    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) return string;

    char[] strArray = string.toCharArray(); // Does this consume space?

    int first = 0, last = strArray.length - 1;

    while (first < last){
        char temp = strArray[first];
        strArray[first++] = strArray[last];
        strArray[last--] = temp;
    }


    return String.valueOf(strArray);
}
```

Does converting the str to a character array consume space

Comment: That might depend on the language. If this is Java, the answer is yes, and you cannot really avoid it if your input is `String`, since it's immutable.

Comment: @amit So does this mean the space complexity is O(k) and not O(1), where k is the length of the string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O Notation for space complexity of converting a string to char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127378/big-o-notation-for-space-complexity-of-converting-a-string-to-char-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`String`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), `toCharArray` creates "a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string". Therefore, calling `toCharArray` has an O(n) space complexity.