# Big O Notation for space complexity of converting a string to char array

Tags: java, big-o

Given a string String str= "absdf"; of N length and if we convert the same string to char Array using -
char [] arr=str.toCharArray();.

Is it consider to be an extra space of O(N) or it will be O(1)?

Comment: O(N). The array has to be copied.

Comment: The array has to be copied because you can mutate the elements of `arr`, but the string has to remain immutable.

Comment: @user strings are backed by a char array, but that's not the array returned by the method.

Answer (score 2):

It is `O(N)` as suggested by @andy, the implementation of `String.toCharArray()` is something like:

```java
public char[] toCharArray() {
  char result[] = new char[value.length];
  // copy the contents
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Time Complexity will be `O(N)`. Similar to creating a new Array equal to the length of the String and copying the String to the Character Array. Creating an array takes `O(N)` time and copying takes `O(N)`. So total worst case complexity will be `O(N)`.

Comment: I think the question is about space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Its O(N)

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

This code is taken from openjdk implementation. We are trying to iterate each element of string and copy it into the each cell of array.
Number of iteration will be length of string.

Comment: I think the question is about space complexity.

Comment: Yup both time and space have same time complexity

Comment: You mean both the time and space complexities are same. You shouldn't say space have time complexity. Space complexity represents how much extra space is used by the program. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Official java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) toCharArray() creates a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of a given string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by the given string. As it's copying each character from string to char array it takes linear time, so Time complexity is O(n), and space complexity is also O(n).